Как дать доступ клиентам в интернет через VPN сервер (OpenConnect VPN server)?
Я пытаюсь настроить OpenConnect VPN сервер. Сервер установлен на машине с публичным IP-адресом 154.154.154.154. Сеть VPN сервера: 192.168.2.0/24. VPN сервер слушает порт 1234 на машине. Таблица роутинга на машине (ip route):
default via 154.154.154.1 dev eth0
192.168.2.0/24 via 154.154.154.154 dev eth0
154.154.154.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 154.154.154.154

Так же включен форвард:

/etc/sysctl.conf: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
/etc/default/ufw: DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
Но выйти в интернет через VPN пока не получается. Но после выполнения этой команды:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
Получается, но трафик идет от устройства клиента (при заходе на 2ip.ru я вижу адрес провайдера клиента, а не публичный адрес машины - 154.154.154.154), а не от VPN сервера. Как сделать так, чтобы трафик шел от VPN сервера?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ И ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ:

Я внес небольшие изменения и вот более подробно и структурированно:
VPS сервер - машина "А":

    1. Белый ip адрес 154.154.154.154

    2. На нем установлен Open Connect VPN сервер:

        2.1. Сеть 192.168.2.0/24

        2.2. Маршрутизатор 192.168.2.1

        2.3. Клиентам дан доступ только к локальной сети (192.168.2.0/24)

        2.4. DNS сервера которые используются VPN сервером:
8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1 (информация об этом
автоматически передается на клиент,
и на клиенте настраивается роутинг
для этих адресов через шлюз 192.168.2.1
и сетевой интерфейс VPN (192.168.2.x)

        2.5. VPN сервер слушает входящие подключения на порту 1234

    3. Роутинг на сервере:

default via 154.154.154.1 dev eth0
192.168.2.0/24 via 154.154.154.154 dev eth0
154.154.154.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 154.154.154.154

Где строчка "192.168.2.0/24 via 154.154.154.154 dev eth0"
отвечает за то, чтобы входящие соединения
к VPN сети устанавливались через шлюз - 
машина "А", для того, чтобы VPN сервер
знал через какой шлюз ему обратно
посылать пакеты.

    4. IP forwarding: включен в ядре и в UFW (firewall).
Добавлена запись iptables:
"iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 154.154.154.154"
для того, чтобы когда устройство
192.168.2.x посылает запрос
(192.168.2.x -> 192.168.2.1 -> UFW)
его IP был публичный и посылал
запрос от имени машины "A"
(UFW -> 154.154.154.1 -> destination).

Устройство клиента - машина "B":

    1. Локальный ip адрес: 192.168.1.x

    2. Шлюз (роутер): 192.168.1.1

При подключении к VPN на клиенте автоматически настраивается роутинг на DNS сервер'а VPN с'ервера и к ним я спокойно подключаюсь через VPN сервер с публичным ip адресом машины "A". Но когда я потом еще настраиваю роутинг ip сайта или полностью весь default трафик (на клиенте) через шлюз 192.168.2.1 через сетевой интерфейс 192.168.2.x этот рутинг почему-то не работает, доступ к сайту пропадает.
Также на клиенте настроен роутинг к 154.154.154.154 (машина "A") через шлюз 192.168.1.1 через сетевой интерфейс 192.167.1.x.
Как настроить роутинг на клиенте, чтобы весь интернет трафик или подключение только к отдельному сайту происходило через VPN сервер и подключение устанавливалось с через белый ip адрес машины "A" ?

через сетевой интерфейс 192.167.1.x.  - тут опечатка? 168 ??? Какая подсеть у клиента? 192.168.2.x /16 или /24 ???

Какая подсеть у клиента в лакальной сети? 192.168.1.x /16 или /24 ???

Да - опечатка. IP-адрес клиента в локальной сети: "192.168.1.x". Подсеть клиента в локальной сети: "192.168.1.x/24", подсеть клиента через VPN: "192.168.2.x/24".

Добавьте в вопрос вывод ip route show до подключения и после подключения к VPN. Чтоб через VPN подключаться только к нужным сайтам, надо получить список их адресов по ипользуемым доменным именам и добавить маршруты.

Сервер Вы видимо настроили, надо и клиентов настроить.
На клиентах, необходимо:

добавить маршрут по умолчанию через VPN, старый default маршрут либо удалить, либо задать ему менее приоритетную метрику, чтоб не мешал.

доавить маршрут к vpn узлу по пути старого default маршрута, иначе перестанет работать vpn из-за зацикливания трафика через самого себя.
default via 192.168.2.1 dev vpn
154.154.154.154/32 via x.x.x.x dev eth0


где: via x.x.x.x dev eth0 - часть старого default маршрута, обеспечивающего прямой доступ в internet.

А) Получается, что все запросы к ДНС идут через VPN сервер, а остальные идут через локал. устройство) Но тогда появляется другой вопрос: команду iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE я заменил на iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j 154.154.154.154, и тоже все работает. Логично, что если эту команду убрать, то ничего работать не будет. Ок, с запросами на ДНС это работает, но когда я перенаправляю на клиенте весь default трафик через 192.168.2.1 (на windows: route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1) - ничего не работает( Почему?

-j 154.154.154.154 - это странно, такого действийствия нет.

Если запросы к DNS дожны идти без VPN, это можно реализовать маршрутизацией, к нужным хостам (IP).

Вместо 192.168.2.1 должен быть адрес VPN-сервера в туннеле.

Ой, я там ошибся: вот команда: iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 154.154.154.154.

А почему не 192.168.2.1? Получается ведь, что у меня есть 2 интерфейс на устройстве клиента - 192.168.2.x, и если отправлять через этот интерфейс, то шлюз как раз это 192.168.2.1? (шлюз клиента без VPN - 192.168.1.1)

Подключение к ДНС тоже должны быть через VPN сервер, и они работают при таком шлюзе (192.168.2.1). Но когда я делаю подключение через VPN для например конкретного сайта, то но просто не грузится...

StackOverflow просит продолжить обсуждение в чате.

Недостаточно информации, нарисуйте (можо текстом, дополнив свой вопрос) схему с адресами для сервера и клиента и какие текущие настройки iptables и route/ip r, ip a.

Вот, более подробно. Насчет тех путей (192.168.2.x -> 192.168.2.1 ->.UFW -> 154.154.154.1 -> destination) я не уверен - это мои догадки.
